# Is there a way to identify what executable made a network connection?

Tags: networking, windows-10

I can identify open connections by

netstat -a

But I wonder if there is a simple way to identify what running exe is making the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Windows Administrative Tools. Select Resource Monitor. Run it and be sure to expand the Network section. This will tell you what processes are using the Network.